# Column header is printed on next page but no detail band

Tags: jasper-reports

I have report which has two pages. First page has column header and detail band. Detail band content ends on first page, but problem is that column header is printed on second page.
According to http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/report-structure-jaspersoft-studio "The column header band is printed at the beginning of each detail column". This is not expected behavior ? Can anyone point me to right direction ?

Picture:[image: This was my example, but purple arrows are part of my solution]
EDIT: new picture to draw explanation

Comment: You need to create a [mcve]  (jrxml, datasource etc) seems like you are passing another empty record, or have some other strange problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer myself, as Petter Friberg pointed out i looked for empty record, new column being created or something similar. Because there was some magical element overflowing on new site, i added borders on every element. In the end i found out that there was text field (marked on picture with purple color) which had something like (simplified):

```
$F{invoice.getText()} != null ? $F{invoice.getText()} : "\n"
```

Text had perfect length to hit me with this  and it was rendering new empty row on new page.